# Constructing a non-vanishing $n$-form on $S^n$

Tags: differential-geometry

How can I go about constructing a smooth non-vanishing $n$-form on $S^n$ using the stereographical coordinates?

Comment: You build an non vanishing $n$ form $\omega$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ and pull it back to $S^n\setminus \{N\}$ using the stereographical projection. You want to choose  $\omega $ in such a way that it admits a smooth extension to the whole $S^n$.

Comment: There are many ways to construct volume forms on a sphere. If you added background and motivation to your post, it would be easier to help you.

Comment: @AmitaiYuval I'm trying to find an $n$-form such that the integral of it over the sphere is $1$. Shall I just divide by the volume?

Comment: If you already have a volume form then yes.